# how to increase the value of an object dependent on the key name

Tags: javascript, object

I want to increase the value depending on the key name. I have an array with scores:

```
[50,50,60,70,80,90,90,100]
```

```
Grade A: score<100 and score>=90
Grade B: score<90 and score>=80
Grade C: score<80 and score>=60
Grade D: score<60 and score>=0
```

In the end, I want to get an object with countable scores:

```
{A:0, B:0, C:0, D:0 };
```

Comment: it will only increase by one each time

Comment: Which properties are you trying to increment and why?

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and use the available static and instance methods of [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods).

Comment: how are the keys related? please add the wanted result.

Comment: I have added more information and am awaiting approval

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+count+all+grades+based+on+array+of+points) of [categorizing and counting numbers in for loop - Javascript](/q/28599961/4642212).

Comment: function countGrade(scores){
  let table = {S:0, A:0, B:0, C:0, D:0, X:0};
  S: table.S+=scores.filter((x=>x===100)).length;
  A: table.A+=scores.filter((x=>x<100&&x>=90)).length;
  B: table.B+=scores.filter((x=>x<90&&x>=80)).length;
  C: table.C+=scores.filter((x=>x<80&&x>=60)).length;
  D: table.D+=scores.filter((x=>x<60&&x>=0)).length;
  X: table.X+=scores.filter((x=>x === -1)).length;
  return table
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) and change dependent properties.

```js
const
    table = { S: 0, A: 0, B: 0, C: 0, D: 0, X: 0 },
    change = new Proxy(table, {
        set: function(obj, prop) {
            if (prop === 'B') obj.S++;
            obj[prop]++;
            return true;
        },
    });

change.B++;

console.log(table);
```